# Custom layout height wrapping content instead of using defined layout height

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a custom_alert.xml layout with the root element as a `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_height="130dp"`. I'm using `AlertDialog.Builder` to create it.

Here's my full XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/avail"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/example" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/Ex"
                        android:textOn="@string/installed"
                        android:textOff="@string/uninstalled"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/example" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/tbEx1"
                        android:textOn="@string/installed"
                        android:textOff="@string/uninstalled"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/example" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/tbEx2"
                        android:textOn="@string/installed"
                        android:textOff="@string/uninstalled"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/example" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/tbEx3"
                        android:textOn="@string/installed"
                        android:textOff="@string/uninstalled"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/example" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/tbEx4"
                        android:textOn="@string/installed"
                        android:textOff="@string/uninstalled"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

As stated, the root element is set at `130dp` but when it's shown on screen, it wraps content, when I want it to be at a specific height so I can use the `ScrollView` to scroll through the entries.

Comment: Is this an AlertDialog ? @ethan

Comment: Yes, I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: I had implemented something similar , let me find the code for example